# rdb2rdf using rdflib but open() does not work

Tags: python, rdflib

i am trying to convert relational db to rdf using rdflib , i tried code
you can find it in this link https://pypi.org/project/rdb2rdf/ but does not work.
i am using SQL server instead of PostgreSQL.
after open() , i print length of graph and give me 0  !!
can any one help

```
import rdflib as _rdf
import sqlalchemy as _sqla
db_str = 'postgresql://testuser:testpasswd@localhost/testdb'
db = _sqla.create_engine(db_str)
graph = _rdf.Graph()
graph.open(db)
print(graph.serialize(format='nt'))
```

Comment: Does it give you an error?

Comment: it does not give me any error @Jesse

Comment: `graph = _rdf.Graph('rdb2rdf_dm')` and something like `db_str = 'mssql://*server_name*/*database_name*?trusted_connection=yes'`.